# Using reserved word in sql update query in php overwrites the whole table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently working on a php project and used the word 'value' as a column name.  The problem being that when I run the query, it overwrites all entries in the database, even though I have a delimiter (primary key = ***).  I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work, and it hasn't yet.  here is the complete line of code:

```
$SqlStatement = "UPDATE rev_exp SET Date_Entered = '".date('Y-m-d')."', Description = '".$_POST['txtUtilityType']." ".$_POST['txtAccountNumber']." ".$_POST['txtDateAdded']."', `Value` = ".$_POST['txtValueBalance'].", Notes = '".$_POST['txtNotes']."' WHERE PK_Rev_Exp = ".$row['FK_Rev_Exp'];
```

Note here, that $row['FK_Rev_Exp'] is the delimiter I was talking about.  It is being pulled accurately from a previous query.  Also, please ignore any sql injection problems, I'm just working on getting the project functional, I can optimize later.

EDIT 1: I have also tried enclosing the "value" in everything I can think of that may get rid of this problem, but no luck.

EDIT 2: I also don't think it is a problem with the statement itself, as I directly entered the statement into the mysql command line and it only affected 1 row, possibly a php problem?

EDIT 3: Full block, including the execution of the sql.  Here, ExecuteSQL runs all necessary mysqli statements to execute the sql command.  it takes in a sql statement and a true/false if there is a result set:

```
$SqlStatement = "UPDATE rev_exp SET Date_Entered = '".date('Y-m-d')."', Description = '".$_POST['txtUtilityType']." ".$_POST['txtAccountNumber']." ".$_POST['txtDateAdded']."', `Value` = '".$_POST['txtValueBalance']."', Notes = '".$_POST['txtNotes']."' WHERE PK_Rev_Exp = ".$row['FK_Rev_Exp'];
ExecuteSQL($SqlStatement, false);
```

I can't figure it out, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you 'print $SqlStatement;' and display output in your question?

Comment: I assume that `txtValueBalance` and `FK_Rev_Exp` are integers?

Comment: Is it `$_POST['txtValueBalance']` an integer?

Comment: outputted statement is here: UPDATE rev_exp SET Date_Entered = '2013-05-17', Description = 'blah blah 45678 2013-05-03', `Value` = 300.00, Notes = 'fortis BC' WHERE PK_Rev_Exp = 48

Comment: Describe your table Structure as Fabio and slientw both has asked common question about Integer and fields

Comment: Date_Entered is a date, Description and Notes are varchar(50), and Value and PK_Rev_Exp are double and bigint respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is not about `mysql reserver keywords` because your correctly surrounded `Value` with backtick and that makes database understand this is a field. I'm more concerned about treating not integers as integers so i would suggest to surround with quotes `''` your value since it is a decimal

```
`Value` = '".$_POST['txtValueBalance']."',
```

Comment: +1 I agree with Fabio. It's no problem if you surround `Value` field's value with single quotes. I was also supposing to give that answer ;)

Comment: Just tried it, didn't fix the problem.  still getting the mass overwrite

Comment: @BlazeHeroic query is correct though problem must be somewhere else, can you add more code?

Comment: previous queries work 100% and subsequent queries are running 100%, its just this query thats giving me trouble

Comment: @BlazeHeroic are you in a loop? it might be that `$row['FK_Rev_Exp']` returns once empty so the query will have  ` WHERE PK_Rev_Exp = ` then it updates all rows, as you are experiencing

Comment: just found it.  apparently already wrote the update script for the rev_exp table, but forgot to put in the WHERE on it, so its updating all then updating the one field over again.  Welcome to 1:45 in the morning coding *facepalms on self*

Comment: @BlazeHeroic eheheh it's ok, important is you fixed. Don't forget to accept answer to help people in the future with similar problems